# Could someone explain how Lagrange's theorem is being applied in this exercise?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

Is group $D_4$ a normal subgroup of $S_4$? The answer I've read does the following:

$|D_4|=8$ , $|S_4|=24$ and $[S_4 : D_4]=3$, so $\forall\sigma\in S_4, [\sigma^3]_{D_4}=[e]_{D_4} \to \sigma^3\in D_4$, which is a contradiction, so $D_4$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

I don't understand the exercise from so $\forall\sigma\in S_4$...

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: I have already changed the title. Is it better now? I accept suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $D_4$ would be normal every element raised to the third power would be an element of $D_4$ (apply Lagrange’s Theorem in the quotient group!). This would mean that $(12)$ and $(1234)$ would be in $D_4$. Can you finish? The notation $ [.]$ is weird but denotes the elements of the quotient $S_4/D_4$.

Comment: After reading your answer, my reasoning is as follows:


1) The group $[S_4 : D_4]$ has order $3$. Like any group of order $n$, it is cyclic if and only if $n$ is a prime number. Then the order of any element of $[S_4 : D_4]$ has order $3$, except the identity. It can also be said that the order of any element of a group must be divisor of the order of the group, so the order must be $3$ except for the identity.


2) For any $a$ it's true that $[a]^3_{D_4}=[a^3]_{D_4}=[e]_{D_4}=D_4$, so $a\in D_4$.

Comment: 3) $D_4$ is a group whose elements can have order $1$,$2$ or $4$, but not order $3$. So it is a contradiction: the elements of $[S_4 : D_4]$ do not form a group because the third power of these should not result in the neutral element for it to make sense.

However, I don't quite see the idea. Something doesn't look right. What reasoning have you followed? I don't understand what you mean by applying Lagrange's theorem to $[S_4 : D_4]$.

Comment: @SergioDuránVega Not quite ad (1)(2): you do not need the fact that the quotient is cyclic (it is though), but only that it's order is $3$. And Lagrange tells you that $\overline{a}^3=\overline{e}$ (I prefer overbar's notation rather than $[ \cdot ]_{\text{normal subgroup}}$. In the original group $S_4$ it means that $a^3 \in D_4$, so *not* $a \in D_4$, as you stated.

Comment: Ad (3): every third power of an element of $S_4$ is in $D_4$, so my point was $(12)^3=(12)$ and $(4321)^3=(1234)$ is in $D_4$. These elements generate the whole of $S_4$, a contradiction. You could also have taken $(12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34)$, since the $2$-cycles generate $S_4$. Hope it is clear now.